# Prove $f''(x)>0$ for some x.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, proof-verification

Question: Let $f$ be a twice differentiable function on $R$. Suppose $f(0) = 0$ and $f(x)/x$ is increasing for $x > 0$, prove $f′′(x) ≥ 0$ for some $x > 0$, but not necessarily for all $x > 0$.

My attempt: 
Since $f(x)/x$ is increasing for $x > 0$, $[f'(x)x-f(x)]/x^2] \geq 0 
\forall x>0$

So $f'(x) \geq [f(x)/x] \forall x>0$

By MVT, $f'(x) \geq f'(c)$ for some $c \in (0,x)$ and  $\forall x>0$

Thus $f'(c)$ is a global minimum of $f'$, and since $f''(x)$ is differentiable, $f'(c)=0$ for some c $\in (0,x)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f'(x) \geq f'(c)$ for some $c \in (0,x),$ by MVT, there is $\xi \in (c,x)$ such that $f'(x)-f'(c)=f''(\xi)(x-c)$. From this equation, it is obvious that $f''(\xi) \ge 0$.

Comment: Much more precise. I like it. Is my logic that $f'(c)$ is a minimum of $f'$, and thus $f''(c)=0$ wrong though?

Comment: You should know that $c$ is a function $c=c(x)$. Different $x$ will bring different $c$. So you can not view $c$ is a minimum of $f'$ at $(0,x)$.